# Why does WordPress still say that my PHP max input vars has not been updated?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm setting up a WordPress site and was prompted to increase my PHP max input vars and the memory limit, but all attempts have reigned no results. I managed to change the memory limit with no issues, however, the input vars still remains the same.

I've created a php.ini file and placed in the root directory, and that didn't work. I created a user.ini file in the same location, didn't work either. I even placed it in the wp-admin file and still no dice. I tried to update the .htaccess file because that was a recommended solution, and still no kosher.

This is the line I've placed within the php.ini file: max_input_vars = 3000

So far I had expected any of the different solutions to have removed that error, but still, nothing has changed and I'm all out of ideas. Any pointers are greatly appreciated, and if more details are needed do let me know and I will add as such.

Answer (score 0):

You may try editing the wp-config file in the document root /var/www/html and add the Directive for wp-config.php. Kindly see it below:

@ini_set( 'max_input_vars' , 4000 );

To gain access to the wp-config file you will need to FTP or SSH to the server.

You may also try editing the php.ini file. In my case, it is located at /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini since I am using apache2 for my wordpress site. You may use the "find / -name *php.ini" command to locate your php.ini file and use vi command to edit the file.

; max_input_vars = 1000

You need to remove the semicolon and change the value that you want to use. Don't forget to restart the Apache service.

$ service apache2 restart

To check if you successfully changed the value, you may create a phpinfo.php file in the document root. Edit the file named phpinfo.php and copy the following code.

`<?php
phpinfo();
?>`

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!